# jQuery Trim String by Width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trim a string down to a particular pixel width so that it can properly fit in a container. It will be similar to substring, except that I am trimming based on pixel width as opposed to number of characters. is there a built in function for this?

Comment: What happens when the pixel width occurs within the space of a letter (say half-way through an 'm')? Do you expand the string to include the full 'm', or round it down to omit the 'm'? Oh, and no, there isn't a built in JS function for this, though CSS does it quite easily.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's your application for this? You could easily just let the string overflow it's container but use `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: @David Thomas: I will omit the 'm' in that case.

Comment: @CrazyJugglerDrummer: I am aware of the overflow: hidden property. however, it is not sufficient in this case because I am adding ellipsis to an overflowing word and text-overflow: ellipsis is not supported in mozilla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via css: `text-overflow: clip;`

Note: This is not supported in FF < 7. Every other browser including IE6 supports it.

Try this:

```
function trimByPixel(str, width) {
    var spn = $('<span style="visibility:hidden"></span>').text(str).appendTo('body');
    var txt = str;
    while (spn.width() > width) { txt = txt.slice(0, -1); spn.text(txt + "..."); }
    return txt;
}
```

Comment: I know. that is not what I'm after.

Comment: FF < 7? I just upgraded to 5.0.1, so I don't think there's even a beta for Firefox 6 yet... :D

Comment: :) You can get FF8 alpha release if you go to nightly builds: http://nightly.mozilla.org/

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:
[jQuery Text Overflow plugin](http://www.bramstein.com/projects/text-overflow/)

Lg
warappa

Answer (score 0):

CSS might be the easiest/best option, especially if you're trying to keep text confined to an area.  Check out both [word-wrap](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/word-wrap-force-text-to-wrap) and [text-overflow](http://deepubalan.com/blog/2010/11/27/text-overflow-css3-property-explained-pure-css-solution-to-get-ellipsis/), as they might be v

Comment: I already know about those and they are not what I'm looking for.